# Python3 - IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

f = sys.argv[1]

seq_records = SeqIO.parse(f, 'fasta')
refseq_record = next(seq_records)

for seq_record in seq_records:
    for i in range(0, len(refseq_record)):
        nt1 = refseq_record[i]
        nt2 = seq_record[i]
        if nt1 != nt2:
            print (seq_record.id, i+1, nt2, nt1)
```

Hello,
I get IndexError: string index out of range error at line 12:
nt2 = seq_record[i]

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Do you expect all elements in `seq_records` to have the same length as `refseq_record`?

Comment: Yes, Jorge Luis

Comment: Obviously they are not.

Comment: We can't help you with this because your question does not contain a [mre]. The reason you get the error is what Jorge said -- `seq_record` is shorter than `refseq_record`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the min value length between the reference sequence and the current sequence

```
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

f = sys.argv[1]

seq_records = SeqIO.parse(f, 'fasta')
refseq_record = next(seq_records)

for seq_record in seq_records:
    min_length = min(len(refseq_record), len(seq_record))
    for i in range(0, min_length):
        nt1 = refseq_record[i]
        nt2 = seq_record[i]
        if nt1 != nt2:
            print(seq_record.id, i + 1, nt2, nt1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because `seq_record` is shorther than the length of `refseq_record`. This would mean that you are trying to access an index in `seq_record` that does not exist. If you add conditional to check that the strings you are comparing are the same length before the second for loop you should be alright.

Abbreviated fix for your code:

```
for record in records:
    if len(seq) == len(refseq):
       cont. your nested for as before
    else:
        print("they are different lengths", seq.id)
```

If you want to read about IndexError: string index out of range: https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-string-index-out-of-range/